# A Comma Between Each Items Except the Last One with get_the_term_list

Tags: terms

I search here and on Google and I can't find answer to my question, just hope you will find it relevant.

I'm doing a magazine website and I need to display names of contributors as a byline. I'm taking the information from the taxonomy 'Contributor' to display their names.

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID , 'contributors', 'By ',' and '); ?>
```

That gives me, By contributor1 and contributor2 and contributor3 and contributor4

But I would like to have something like that instead:

**By contributor1, contributor2, contributor3 and contributor4**

Maybe it's not possible, let me know.

Thanks in advance,

François

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_the_term_list` uses [`get_the_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) to fetch the term objects. You can use that function instead and build the list however you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

[If you look at the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1392)...

```
1420             */
1421            $term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-$taxonomy", $links );
1422    
1423            return $before . join( $sep, $term_links ) . $after;
1424    }
```

... you will see that there is no filter that will allow you to alter the string in a way that effects where the separator occurs.

You could pipe the output through some `regex` but `regex` on markup is tricky and prone to error. You'd be better off copying that core function, renaming it, and altering it to do what you need.